# AccessibilityNodeInfo ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, crash, accessibility

Using the Android Accessibility Service.

On Android 8.0 (only) I have a lot of crash with:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=5 srcPos=0 dst.length=5 dstPos=3 length=5
       at java.lang.System.arraycopy(System.java)
       at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:591)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.init(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3212)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.refresh(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:867)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityCache$AccessibilityNodeRefresher.refreshNode(AccessibilityCache.java:564)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityCache.refreshCachedNodeLocked(AccessibilityCache.java:206)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityCache.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityCache.java:170)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityInteractionClient.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityInteractionClient.java:541)
       at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:1709)
```

This Stacktrace doesn't contain any line from my own code.

I cannot reproduce it on my side and I have no idea on how to fix it. Do you?

Comment: This is system bug - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68299168

Comment: Yes, I'm asking on both channel to hopefully get an answer :(

Comment: @stankocken Do you found any solution?

Comment: OEM needs to provide an update for 8.0.0. This issue is fixed in 8.1. Reference  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110745329